# Why not firebase fields not getting updated?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update my firebase database based on "aadhar" field but I am failing to do it so. I don't know where it is going wrong.

Here is my activity code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_details);
    db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    individualName  = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.IndividualName);
    individualFatherName=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.FatherName);
    individualAge=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.Age);
    individualHouseNo=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.HouseNumber);
    individualAadhar=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.AadharNumber);
    individualPhno=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.MobileNumber);
    individualPreferredUnit=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.Preferredunit);
    individualBankName=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.BankName);
    individualBankAccNo=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.BankACCNumber);
    individualName.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uname").toString());
    individualFatherName.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ufname").toString());
    individualAge.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uAge").toString());
    individualHouseNo.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uHnumber").toString());
    individualAadhar.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uAadharNumber").toString());
    individualPhno.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uMobileNo").toString());
    individualPreferredUnit.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uPreferredUnit").toString());
    individualBankName.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uBankName").toString());
    individualBankAccNo.getEditText().setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uBankAccNumber").toString());
    indivName = individualName.getEditText().getText().toString();
    fatherName = individualFatherName.getEditText().getText().toString();
    age = individualAge.getEditText().getText().toString();
    houseNumber = individualHouseNo.getEditText().getText().toString();
    aadharNumber = individualAadhar.getEditText().getText().toString();
    mobileNumber = individualPhno.getEditText().getText().toString();
    preferredunit = individualPreferredUnit.getEditText().getText().toString();
    bankName = individualBankName.getEditText().getText().toString();
    bankACCNumber = individualBankAccNo.getEditText().getText().toString();


}

public void submitButton(View view) {
    updateData(aadharNumber,indivName,fatherName,age,houseNumber,mobileNumber,preferredunit, bankName,bankACCNumber);
}

public void updateData(String aadharNumber,String name,String fname, String age,String houseNo,String mobileNumber,String preferredUnit,String bankName,String bankACCnumber){
    Map<String, Object> individualInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    individualInfo.put("name", name.trim());
    individualInfo.put("fatherName", fname.trim());
    individualInfo.put("age", age.trim());
    individualInfo.put("houseNo", houseNo.trim());
    individualInfo.put("phoneNo", mobileNumber.trim());
    individualInfo.put("preferredUnit", preferredUnit.trim());
    individualInfo.put("bankName", bankName.trim());
    individualInfo.put("bankAccNo", bankACCnumber.trim());

    db.collection("individuals").whereEqualTo("aadhar",aadharNumber)
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                     if(task.isSuccessful() && !task.getResult().isEmpty()){
                         DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot=task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0);
                         String documentID=documentSnapshot.getId();
                         db.collection("individuals")
                                 .document(documentID)
                                 .update(individualInfo)
                                 .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                         Toast.makeText(userDetails.this, "Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     }
                                 }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                 Toast.makeText(userDetails.this, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                         });

                     }else{

                         Toast.makeText(userDetails.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
        }
    });

}
```

I am getting the fields from Firebase and updating the field which using "aadhar" field.

Here is my firebase db

```
aadhar:"1234"
age:"1234"
bankAccNo:"1234"
bankName:"1234"
ctrApproved:"1234"
fatherName:"1234"
houseNo:"1234"
laApproved:"1234"
name:"1234"
phoneNo:"1234"
preferredUnit:"1234"
psUpload:"1234"
remarks:"1234"
secOfficerApproved:"1234"
secOfficerUpload:"1234"
spApproved:"1234"
```

Data is not getting updated but I am getting "Successfully Updated" Toast without any changes in DB.

Comment: Have sent right data to firestore ? Because I think you are getting value before entering in to edit text. Put log and check your data just before you sending to firestore

Comment: Have you tried to update a single field? Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes, I am filling the editTextInput field and if any changes occur they need to be updated.